# Filestream - To another server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a software developer and I am not really familiar with the new FILESTREAM feature on SQL Server 2008+. However it looks really helpful for what I am working on.

Due to strict company policies, is it possible to have the files save to another server than the SQL server itself? So instead of saving to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA, I would like it to save to another server's D drive or something.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Due to strict company policies, is it possible to have the files save
>   to another server than the SQL server itself?

Answer: Yes

I believe the feature you're looking for is Remote BLOB Store:

> Remote BLOB Store (RBS) is designed to move the storage of large
>   binary data (BLOBs) from database servers to commodity storage
>   solutions.

Source: [Remote BLOB Store Provider Library Implementation Specification](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc905212.aspx)

References:

[SQL Remote Blob Storage Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlrbs/)

[Microsoft SQL Remote Blob Storage (RBS) Samples](https://sqlrbs.codeplex.com/)

[Deploying Remote BLOB Storage with SQL Server 2012 AlwaysOn Availability Groups](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2013/05/23/deploying-remote-blob-storage-with-sql-server-2012-alwayson-availability-groups.aspx)